# Decoding compiler output for interface run type assertion

Tags: go

I recently encountered empty interfaces while using the `Load()` method of `Atomic.Value` . I was experimenting with empty interfaces type assertion a bit - https://play.golang.org/p/CLyY2y9-2VF

This piqued my interest, and I decided to take a peek behind the curtains to see what actions does a compiler take so that the code doesn't panic in case of trying to read the concrete value on a `nil` interface {} (e.g., when you call `Load.(type)` when Store hasn't been called yet).

I could see that in the unsafe version, compiler had this assembly instruction that cause the panic : call runtime.panicdottypeE(SB)

The panic instruction is obviously not present in the safe version. Can someone please explain this in more details on what compiler is doing when we capture return value with ok (and perhaps point me to the corresponding assembly instructions in the godbolt link)?

Here are the godbolt compiler links for unsafe version [1] and safe version [2].

[1] https://godbolt.org/z/76onvj

[2] https://godbolt.org/z/e8aoqe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty interface type (called `eface` in runtime package) is 2 pointers, first one to underlying type (e.g. bool type, int type, YourStruct type, ...) second one is a pointer to data (IIRC in some cases the data itself).

Unsafe version:

```
call "".returnEmptyInterface(SB)   Call the function
pcdata $0, $1                      pcdata is not a real instruction, ignore 
movq 8(SP), AX                     AX <- pointer to data 
movq    (SP), CX                   CX <- pointer to type 
pcdata $0, $2 
leaq type.bool(SB), DX             DX <- pointer to bool type 
cmpq CX, DX                        Compare CX and DX 
jne main_pc156                     If they are not equal jump to main_pc156
```

In main_pc156 compiler will call runtime.panicdottypeE that will basically panic. Source code from `runtime/iface.go` (can find it in your `$GOPATH/src`):

```
func panicdottypeE(have, want, iface *_type) {
    panic(&TypeAssertionError{iface, have, want, ""})
}
```

Safe version:

```
pcdata  $0, $0
pcdata  $1, $0
call    "".returnEmptyInterface(SB)    Call the function
pcdata  $0, $1
movq    8(SP), AX                      AX <- pointer to data
movq    (SP), CX                       CX <- pointer to type
main_pc47:
pcdata  $0, $2
leaq    type.bool(SB), DX              DX <- pointer to bool type
cmpq    CX, DX                         Compare CX and DX
jne     main_pc186                     If not equal jump main_pc186
pcdata  $0, $3
movblzx (AX), AX                       AX <- dereference AX
main_pc62:
```

and in main_pc186

```
pcdata  $0, $3
xorl    AX, AX                        AX <- 0
jmp     main_pc62                     Jump back at the end of previous block
```

Here `AX` corresponds to `x` in the code but what corresponds to `ok` in code? Nothing! If you check code of `println` you see:

```
cmpq    CX, DX                        Compare CX and DX
seteq   AL                            AL <- 1 if CX equal to DX otherwise 0
```

So compiler decided to compare them again when printing.

Comment: The last time I checked, the data in an interface were always indirected through a pointer, even if the data would fit in the same slot. There was some comment somewhere that said "we plan to change this, try not to rely on it" or something along those lines. Since such a change would mess with the ABI it probably won't happen until Go 2.x.

Comment: @torek I checked, Go had this feature and it got removed. Check older versions like https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.7/src/runtime/iface.go it's filled with  `isDirectIface` checks.

Comment: Aha, so I got the direction backwards: it had been optimized, and was de-optimized! :-) (I wonder why, now.)

Answer (score 0):

The quick summary: they do exactly the same thing, it's just that the case for `ok == false` is different.

The two bits have the following in common:

```
        pcdata  $0, $0
        pcdata  $1, $0
        call    "".returnEmptyInterface(SB)
        pcdata  $0, $1
        movq    8(SP), AX
        movq    (SP), CX
        pcdata  $0, $2
        leaq    type.bool(SB), DX
        cmpq    CX, DX
        jne     main_pc156   <==== jump
        pcdata  $0, $3
        movblzx (AX), AX
```

The code found in `main_pc156` is the part we care about. As you noticed, for the single-value type assertion, this is:

```
main_pc156:
        movq    DX, 8(SP)
        pcdata  $0, $1
        leaq    type.interface {}(SB), AX
        pcdata  $0, $0
        movq    AX, 16(SP)
        call    runtime.panicdottypeE(SB)
        xchgl   AX, AX
```

There's no escaping this, once we jump to `main_pc156`, we panic.

On the other hand, the code for the two-value type assertion is:

```
main_pc186:
        pcdata  $0, $3
        xorl    AX, AX
        jmp     main_pc62
```

This is massively different from the previous case, and takes us right back to the end of the first bit of code, resuming execution.